# can php and javascript work together in an html document? if yes, how?

Tags: php

i want to use php and javascript togethar in a single html document. but i dont know how to use it. Please help me out and let me know what will the proper extension used for such a file.

Answer (score 7):

First, note that :

- PHP is executed on the server -- when generating an HTML page, typically
- Javascript is executed on the client *(browser)* -- when displaying that HTML page, typically.

Generally speaking, you will have a `.php` file on your server.

That PHP file will generate an HTML page -- which may contain Javascript code.

Once the HTML page is received by the browser, it will be displayed, and Javascript will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

php can't work in an html file. php only works in php files. you can add html and javascript in php files easily.

Answer (score 1):

The can work together. The do not work simultanously.

PHP work when the page was at server.

JS work the page goes to browser.